# How to pass variable value to feature title in karate summary report?

Tags: karate

I wrote a feature and a reusable feature, and this is the result in karate summary report below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kklj.png)

However, I want to pass variable value to the report sub-title and makes it more readable. Below is what I want to get.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TJWJ.png)

Is there any way we can customize the report in this way?

I have read the question on passing variable to karate feature line and scenario name. However it doesnt work on reusable feature, because for reusable feature it wont show as a normal scenario in karate report....

Thanks a lots!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Karate we recommend that re-use is done only for "utilities" and not the main domain flows in your test.

Do consider using a `Scenario Outline` to loop like this, because it will appear in the report as a "normal" `Scenario`.

An enhancement released in 1.3.0.RC2 may give you what you are looking for: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1905

Else please assume this is not supported, but open-source code contributions are welcome.

Comment: Tks a lots Peter! Very precise and firm!